# Problems with web application after moving from Windows to Linux host

Tags: java, jquery, linux

I have developed an web application using `xhtml, jQuery, Ajax, java, Servlets & tomcat` on window machine. This application is running quite well on my Windows machine but now I have uploaded it to a Linux machine.

There are some problem I am getting on Linux machine e.g.

***Web page resolution & size:*** I fixed it but want some more suggestion on it. If anybody has faced any similar situation.

***jQuery/javascript:*** Some functionality isn't working on the Linux machine and I am not able to figured it out. I guess javascript/jQuery functions should be defined in a Linux way. Please give me some ideas on it.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you expect us to do with this...

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: to sort the error i am getting on Linux machine. I want to know the reason of error on Linux machine. If application is running quite well on Windows then what could be reason of error on Linux machine?

Comment: What is the error? Javascript runs in your browser, how could you have built an app without knowing this?

Comment: @user575363: Yes, you already said that. When are you going to give us anything we can use in order to do so?

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, you need to explain the _exact_ problems you're having, including error messages, relevant server logs, etc.  You have provided us practically nothing to go on.

Comment: @ Kim Jong Woo :  User click on given layout image, OnClick event Send request to server via Ajax(success), received response (success but getting error when js function need to displaying this incomming response on web page)

Comment: More detail is required. What browser are you testing on? What is the Javascript error? We can't read your mind! This has nothing to do with your operating system, it's JS so it runs in your browser.

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo: ok ok.. i only wanted to know,if there is any special guideline for linux and i got that answer. now i can figured it out while i was confused in linux Vs Windows. BTW thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your second issue, Linux is not affecting your javascript, **but the browser does**. So you don't have to define your javascript "in a linux way" as you say, just be sure your javascript code is as cross-browser as possible OR use the same browser in both operating systems.

For example, your page should behave the same in Firefox for Windows and Firefox for Linux.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Villegas Alvarado: is it? ohk then it might be possible some error in my generated WAR file of project. let me check. Thanks